# /home being read as part of root file system and it's 100% full out of 20GB

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems

```
root@root:~# sudo du -ch --max-depth=1 --exclude=/home/ /
du: cannot access ‘/sys/kernel/slab/L2TP/IPv6’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/sys/kernel/slab/L2TP/IP’: No such file or directory

0   /sys
4.0K    /dev
76M /tmp
30M /lib
16K /lost+found
25M /sbin
977M    /usr
4.0K    /mnt
17M /boot
4.0K    /lib64
97G /home
14M /etc
4.0K    /srv
9.6M    /bin
8.0K    /media
856K    /root
876K    /run
676M    /var
4.0K    /opt
du: cannot access ‘/proc/7076/task/7076/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/7076/task/7076/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/7076/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/7076/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
0   /proc
99G /
99G total



97G /home
```

I don't know what to do s:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it! It wasn't what I thought it was. I checked deleted filess that were still open.

lsof | grep deleted

ps -ef | grep PIDHERE

then

## kill PID